# Plotting the surface of a sphere onto a circle

Tags: python, plot, geometry, geometry-surface

I am trying to create an animation of a sphere rotating but only 2π of the surface of this object can be seen, so I require the ability to plot regions (separation into longitude and latitude) onto a circle and to have them defined by parameters such that they can be altered for rotation using two angles (theta and phi from spherical polar coordinates).

I have tried a few things, but the only time a made anything worthwhile was using tricontour:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np
from math import *

r=1.0 
N=360

circlexy = np.asarray([[r*cos(radians(i)), r*sin(radians(i))]
                   for i in np.arange(0,N,0.1)])
circlez = [r*(cos(radians(j)))*sin(radians(j))
       for j in np.arange(0,N,0.1)]

x1 = circlexy[:,0]
y1 = circlexy[:,1]
z1=circlez

plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tricontourf(x1, y1, z1, 3)
plt.show()
```

However, this plot is not very smooth and even if it were to be it is not very helpful as z1 is required to be the same length as x1 and y1 and so I cannot see a way to define two angles (this plot only rotates in one plane).

I could well have made errors above as my experience in coding is not particularly broad. What would be best to use to make such a plot? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's good to add a language tag to your questions

Comment: OK, sorry about that, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I'm not clear what kind of plot you really want. I usually look at http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html and find something similar to what I want

Comment: Yes I have had a look through this library and I do not believe any of the plots are suitable, the closest being the contour plots but they are not versatile enough for my needs. Although I could well be wrong. I require something that can plot contours (or any type of distinct regions) on a circle and these contours must be able to be created through the input of spherical polar coordinates (r, theta, phi) and therefore it should be possible to change the parameters such that rotation can be imitated in both planes.